# For cycle always give same output

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**1. Summarize the problem**

The following for cycle keeps on running as i want, but always give me the same clicked button that is "0".
It does not give me an error. But by playing the game i can see that it's always the same number.

**2. Describe what you've tried**

I've tried searching around the internet for people like me. but sadly i couldn't find anything.

**3. Show some code**

Code that i'm talking about.

```
    int ButtonNum;

public void Start()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ButtonsPage.Length; i++)
    {
        ButtonsPage[i].GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(delegate { ButtonClicked(ButtonNum); });
    }
}

public void ButtonClicked(int i)
{
    Debug.Log("Clicked" + i);
    if (WhichType == "Nose")
    {
        NoseColor.sprite = NosesColor[i];
        NoseOutline.sprite = NosesOutline[i];
    }
    //ButtonNum will be used to say which one is clicked. Still haven't add it though cause i wanted to fix this problem before
}
```

Comment: TBH I don't see any code producing any output. Also what is `ButtonNum`?

Comment: by output i meant the "add listener".
ButtonNum should send with the listener the number of the clicked button

Comment: How is it supposed to send it? Can you please add the relevant code (i.e. for `ButtonClicked` and `ButtonNum` declaration)

Comment: sure wait. imma open the program

Comment: @GuruStron added more script

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Captured variable in a loop in C#](/q/271440/90527)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not modifying `ButtonNum` in any way, I assume the goal is to use `i` as button number, try changing your code to:

```cs
public void Start()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ButtonsPage.Length; i++)
    {
        var temp = i;
        ButtonsPage[i].GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(delegate { ButtonClicked(temp); });
    }
}
```

Temporary variable is required due to how [closures work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/271447/2501279) in C#.